# How to create HTML block of code in readme.md?

Tags: html, markdown

I want to replace markdown syntax into html tags in my `readme.md` file.

In order to replace the inline code *( single backtics ` )* `` `let a = 10;` `` I use `<code></code>` html tag.

How can I replace the markdown code blocks *( triple backtips ``` )* with html tag?

Is there any equivalent? `<blockquote>`, `<samp>`, `<kbd>` seems  not to work on `github.com` or `npmjs.com`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand, but if I do, in most cases, code blocks in HTML are done by nesting `<code>` in `<pre>`, so like this:

```
<pre>
    <code>
        Whatever code you want to show
    </code>
</pre>
```

Keep in mind, how it looks like depends on CSS for `pre code`

Comment: `pre` seems to work on github description, thanks :)